# JCRE Behavior after receiving an SELECT APDU command

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

As far as I know, When *JCRE* Receive an *SELECT* APDU command, first of all, it search its registry table for the *AID* that the command indicates. If it doesn't found the AID in its *Registry Table* returns `6A82`. But if *JCRE* found it, it will call the `deselect()` method of the selected applet, and after receiving a `True`, It will call `select()` method of the requested applet. if it receive a `True` from that method, mark that applet as selected.

My questions:

1- What happens if the first applet (Currently Selected Applet) returns `False` when *JCRE* calls its `deselect()` method? Does the applet remains `Selected`?

2- What happens if the second applet (The requested Applet) returns `False` when *JCRE* calls its `select()` method?which one of applets will be select in this case? the default is Security Domain?

Comment: I already read this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958082/some-questions-about-select-apdu-command-in-javacards
But it doesn't help me to receive the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What happens if the first applet (Currently Selected Applet) returns `false` when JCRE calls its `deselect()` method? Does the applet remain selected?**

No, once the `Applet.deselect()` method was called and returned, the applet will be deselected. There is no way for the applet to prevent this. The [`Applet.deselect()`](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/Applet.html#deselect%28%29) does not have a return value. Even throwing an exception in this method would still not prevent the applet from being deselected.

**What happens if the second applet (the requested Applet) returns `false` when JCRE calls its `select()` method? Which one of the applets will be select in this case?**

As the previous applet has already been deselected and the new applet refused to be selected, *no* applet will be selected then.